# Run cmd command work but run from batch file doesn't

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to create script with for loop to move file to sub folder. 
At the beginning, I work with `CMD` then I copy command to `.bat` file and run it.
The result is nothing happens.
Why the same command on `CMD` works but run from file not ?

Here is my command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
SET FOL=J:\test
SET ENDNUM=2

for /l %x in (1, 1, %ENDNUM%) do (
md "%FOL%/0%x/subfolder"
move /Y "%FOL%\0%x\*" "%FOL%\0%x\subfolder"
)
```

Comment: You have mixed `/` and \ too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to double-up the percentage signs on `for` commands in a batch file.

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %ENDNUM%) do (
  md "%FOL%/0%%x/subfolder"
  move /Y "%FOL%\0%%x\*" "%FOL%\0%%x\subfolder"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check encoding of your .bat file. When I used UTF-8, command prompt displayed error:

```
C:\Users\***\Desktop>´╗┐cmd
'´╗┐cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I used ANSI encoding, the .bat file worked as expected.