# Why do you need to change things in a batch file vs on the command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When entering a command manually it works fine, but when using that same command in a batch file it errors out. HOW to fix it has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128185/run-cmd-command-work-but-run-from-batch-file-doesnt), but I am wondering WHY you have to change things.

The linked example is that when using a for statement in a batch file, the variables need two  percent (%) signs instead of one.

On the cmd line:

```
for %f in folder move ...
```

From a batch file:

```
for %%f in folder move ...
```

Comment: Have you gone thru [\[ this \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509652/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-a-cmd-file) question?

Comment: Because Microsoft says so.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?`

Comment: And you can read: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1417694)